# How To Confirm Stripe PaymentIntent In Server Side Integration Test

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an integration test connected to Stripe (test mode) and I would like to test the complete flow, i.e. creating payment-intent and handling the webhook of `succeeded` event. The first part is pretty straightward. Now for the second part, Obviously I can't do actual flow on the Element widget. So I tried to manually confirm the payment intent (as part of the test code) with the following call:

```kotlin
    fun confirmPaymentIntent(pi: PaymentIntent): PaymentIntent {
        val params = PaymentIntentConfirmParams.builder()
            .addExpand("latest_charge")
            .setPaymentMethod("pm_card_visa") // Don't know what's the correct value!
            .setReturnUrl("https://example.com/return")
            .build()
        return pi.confirm(params)
    }
```

And it works fine, I receive the "payment intent succeeded" event in the webhook. Now the problem is that the real payment flow would contain billing details. So I tried the following:

```kotlin
            .setPaymentMethodData(
                PaymentIntentConfirmParams.PaymentMethodData.builder()
                    .setBillingDetails(
                        BillingDetails.builder()
                            .setAddress(BillingDetails.Address.builder().setCountry("US").build())
                            .setName("My Customer")
                            .setEmail("customer@example.com")
                            .build()
                    )
                    .build()
            )
```

But when I run the code, it's complaining about missing `type` in the payment method data. `Type` enum doesn't have `card` and I have no idea what is the correct value.
In my case, the application supports only cards and it doesn't care about the card details in any way (so anything works, like fake card, token, etc, as long as I get the payment intent event with the name and email info in the webhook.)
First, is there any better way to do this? Second, if not, then how can I manually confirm a payment intent in the test to be able to verify webhook call? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the `payment_intent.succeeded` event directly via [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test#supported-events). If that still doesn't give you the information to test, you would want to build an end-to-end frontend confirmation flow using PaymentElement. It's [not that complicated](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements).